# Zend_Paginator with result of Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

Tags: zend-framework, zend-paginator

i have many class in model directory that those are extend of Zend_Db_Table_Abstract.

but i need use of zend_paginator and this need to result of Zend_Db_Select !!

so when i use of this code (productCat is a model class)

```
$productCat = new ProductCat();
    $rows = $productCat->FetchOrderByPriority();

    // Get a Paginator object using Zend_Paginator's built-in factory.
    $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($rows);
$this->view->paginator = $paginator;
```

it don`t work!

it show me this error :

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Zend_Db_Table_Row could not be converted to string in
```

this is my view code :

```
<ul><?php foreach ($this->paginator as $item): ?> 
<li><?php echo $item; ?></li><?php endforeach; ?></ul>
```

is there any idea?

Comment: Please provide more information than "it don't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pagination definitely works. The problem is in your view where you're trying to `echo $item`.

And it obviously doesn't work since `Zend_Paginator::factory($rows)` has returned a rowset; so when you're iterating over `$paginator` object, you're getting objects of `Zend_Db_Table_Row` type, and you simply cannot `echo` them.

What you're trying to do, I believe, is to `echo` a particular property of the `item` object, something like:

```
echo $item->name;
```